# Java jar load with windows startup issue

Tags: java

I'm using the following code to add a registry entry to HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run :

```
try {
            r.exec("reg add HKCU\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run /v SnShut /t REG_SZ /d " + System.getProperty("user.dir")+ "\\SnShutd.jar");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ShutdownForm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
```

The above create the entry successfully and the app starts automatically on Windows startup, but the problem is that every time starts with the default settings and doesn't load the conf.properties file which is in app's folder in the same place with the jar file. 
Why this happens? I can see via regedit that the path for the app is correct. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Show us the app code that loads from a config file.

Comment: The working directory isn't the jar directory!

Comment: So, how can I get the jar directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the jar path into MANIFEST.MF as below

```
Class-Path: \C:\yourPath\
```

If your config file need to be external from JAR and in a user defined directory try to get the jar path as below:

> YourClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()

Comment: But I don't want the path to be fixed. Maybe a user put the jar dir in another folder or disk.

Comment: Than you have to put your config file inside the jar!

Answer (score 0):

I think, Mauretto has right.

Your Java code should find out the place of its jar, find the .properties file next to it, and read it herein.

Google Guavac can do this to much better, as the base j2se API. For example, you can embed .properties or any resources  of any type into the main .jar, and read it in from 1 simple API-Call.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to keep the config.properties file to the classpath but this way I cannot write to the file, so it loads only the default values. I don't know if I'm doing something wrong or the properties file cannot be written if it's in the internal jar's directory, but I found a different way to solve my problems.
I used preferenses instead and I've managed to store/restore the values without problems.

```
Preferences prefs = Preferences.userRoot().node(this.getClass().getName());
     //get the preferences
    String B = this.prefs.get("Hours", "0");
    String A = this.prefs.get("Mins", "0");
    boolean C = this.prefs.getBoolean("Autostart", false);

    //save preferences
    prefs.put("Hours", spHours.getModel().getValue().toString());
    prefs.put("Mins", spMinutes.getModel().getValue().toString());
    if(cbAutostart.isSelected()==true){
        prefs.putBoolean("Autostart", true);
    }else
        prefs.putBoolean("Autostart", false);
```

Comment: You can't write properties file inside the jar. Your alternative solition is good. Another way is to set just the installation path in Preferences at setup time, than you can use that "base path" for your config files.